# Desktop app converter fails to run, with: "The data area passed to a system call is too small"

Tags: desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have installed Desktop App Converter from the Windows store.
When I try to run the app (literally just launch it), I get the message:

```
[Window Title]
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DACTileLauncher.exe

[Content]
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DACTileLauncher.exe

The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

I have tried running the [Troubleshooter for Windows Apps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/69e76f90-d54c-44cf-9851-c2d1542790db/run-the-troubleshooter-for-windows-apps), it tells me that "Windows Store cache and licenses may be corrupt" and tries to fix them, but running the troubleshooter a second time gives the same issue.

Each time I try to run the Desktop App Converter, I get 2 errors in Event Viewer:

```
%1: Cannot create the Desktop AppX container for package %2 because an error was encountered configuring the runtime.

%4: Cannot create the process for package %1 because an error was encountered while configuring runtime. %5
```

... both from AppModel-runtime

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot from here?

Comment: Are you using Creator Update(15063)?

Comment: Yes - 15063.332

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with the Microsoft DAC you [try this new converter](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/02a95b59-9123-4360-be59-a3a60e39a1fd/desktop-converter-desktop-bridge-setup-converter-a-better-dac-with-gui?forum=wpdevelop#02a95b59-9123-4360-be59-a3a60e39a1fd), it is much easier to use, it has a GUI (no command line), built-in support for digital signing and allows you to customize the list of files that get inside your AppX.

Also, you can generate AppX packages for applications which do not (cannot) install silently.

It runs on Windows 7 too, not just Windows 10 (*recommended*).